# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error for a custom Yocto layer

Tags: makefile, embedded-linux, yocto, nmea2000

I want to create a Yocto layer for the [CANBOAT Repository](https://github.com/canboat/canboat/) for **phyBOARD Mira board** which will be connected to a NMEA2000 on a boat. I would like to read different PGN values and store it in a database.

#### configuration

I have a Linux Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

```
Linux ubuntu 4.13.0-39-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 16:43:10 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have all the `meta` layers in a folder called `sources` in the `$YOCTO_DIR`. Within the `sources` I have created the `meta-canboat` layer with following structure:

```
├── conf
│   └── layer.conf
├── COPYING.MIT
├── README
└── recipes-canboat
    └── canboat
        └── canboat.bb
```

**canboat.bb** is based on the [Yocto-Mega-Manual for Makefile](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#new-recipe-makefile-based-package)

```
SUMMARY = "CANBOAT"
SECTION = "base"
LICENSE = "GPLv3"
#DEPENDS = "xsltproc"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://GPL;md5=05507c6da2404b0e88fe5a152fd12540"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/canboat/canboat.git;branch=${SRCBRANCH}"
SRCBRANCH = "master"
SRCREV = "93b2ebfb334d7a9750b6947d3a4af9b091be2432"

do_compile() {// this is not necessary for Yocto
    make
}
do_install() { // for Makefile Packages do_install is necessary
   oe_runmake install DESTDIR=${D}
}
```

#### build and error

in the `build` directory I execute

```
  bitbake canboat
```

and obtain the error log:

```
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| mkdir -p rel/linux-x86_64
| for dir in actisense-serial analyzer n2kd nmea0183 ip group-function candump2analyzer socketcan-writer; do make -C $dir; done
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/actisense-serial'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/actisense-serial -I../common actisense-serial.c ../common/common.c
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/actisense-serial'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/analyzer'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/analyzer -I../common pgn.c analyzer.c ../common/common.c
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/analyzer'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/n2kd'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/n2kd -I../common main.c gps_ais.c nmea0183.c ../common/common.c -lm
| cp n2kd_monitor ../rel/linux-x86_64/n2kd_monitor
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/n2kd'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/nmea0183'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/nmea0183-serial  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -I../common nmeareader.c ../common/common.c
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/nmea0183'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/ip'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/iptee  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -I../common iptee.c ../common/common.c
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/ip'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/group-function'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/command-group-function -I../common command.c ../common/common.c
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/request-group-function -I../common request.c ../common/common.c
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/group-function'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/candump2analyzer'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/candump2analyzer -I../common candump2analyzer.c ../common/common.c -lm
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/candump2analyzer'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/socketcan-writer'
| arm-phytec-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3   -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/canboat/1.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux= -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-3=  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o ../rel/linux-x86_64/socketcan-writer -I../analyzer -I../common socketcan-writer.c ../analyzer/pgn.c ../common/common.c
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/socketcan-writer'
| make -C analyzer json
| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/analyzer'
| ../rel/linux-x86_64/analyzer -explain-xml >pgns.xml && xsltproc pgns2json.xslt pgns.xml >pgns.json
```

> | /bin/sh: ../rel/linux-x86_64/analyzer: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

```
| Makefile:33: recipe for target 'json' failed
| make[1]: *** [json] Error 126
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/git/analyzer'
| Makefile:29: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.47581:1 exit 2 from 'make'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/canboat/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.47581)
```

I understand that there might be incompatibility for `-x86_64` binaries on `gnueabi` platforms. How can I compile this repository in order to overcome this incompatibility?

### GitHub Repo

[meta-canboat](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/meta-canboat)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what the binary does: do the results of the binary depend on the architecture the tool runs on? If you add details to the question, someone might be able to provide a more detailed answer.

Option 1: If the tool results are independent of architecture, then you can first compile a "native" (i.e. build host arch) version of canboat and then make sure the target build depends on the native one and uses the tools from the native build. This will mean small changes in the recipe and some changes in the Makefiles

Option 2: If the results do depend on arch, you might have to use qemu to run the tool.

There are examples of both cases inside the poky sources.

There may be a third option: if the files are not needed for the build to succeed otherwise, you could run the tool in a postinstall script on first boot/install (and modify the build system to not do it during build).

Comment: According to the [wiki](https://github.com/canboat/canboat/wiki/Building) `It is built regularly on Linux (x86), Linux (armv7), Darwin (Mac OS X) and Windows x86 (under Cygwin).` I tried running it on the VM and it installs without an error

Comment: Sure but compiling in VM and then running in VM is not cross-compiling like Yocto is.

Comment: Btw, based on a quick look that project has probably never been cross compiled: you will probably end up having to fix several things (look at e.g. the PLATFORM variable -- that is bound to go wrong when you build on x86-64 but target is arm...)

Comment: I created a SDK for the Board and tried making the repository again with the variables from the sdk. It still provides the same error. Why would that occur?